# Pipenv install acting weird

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenv, pipenv

Whenever I use pipenv install to download something for my project or even set it up I get this issue. If anyone has had this issue before I'd love to hear what you did to solve it.

```
 C:/Users/blahblah/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe (3.7.9) to create virtualenv...
[ ===] Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.7.9.final.0-32 in 314ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\Abele's desktop\.virtualenvs\stuff-v8dpyd7P, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\Abele's desktop\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.3, setuptools==51.3.3, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

Successfully created virtual environment!
Failed to load paths:   File "<string>", line 1
    import sysconfig, distutils.sysconfig, io, json, sys; paths = {u'purelib': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=0)),u'stdlib': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('stdlib')),u'platlib': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=1)),u'platstdlib': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('platstdlib')),u'include': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=0)),u'platinclude': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=1)),u'scripts': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('scripts')),u'py_version_short': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_version()), }; value = u'{0}'.format(json.dumps(paths));fh = io.open('c:/users/abele'~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpexmxm2ea.json', 'w'); fh.write(value); fh.close()
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Output:
Virtualenv location: C:\Users\blahblah\.virtualenvs\stuff-v8dpyd7P
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Updated Pipfile.lock (a65489)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a65489)...
  ================================ 0/0 - 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

Comment: It seems it has a problem with your user folder paths: `io.open('c:/users/abele'~1/...` Do you have spaces in your user folder path?

Comment: It seems you edited the C:\Users\ path to "blahblah" in your post, but a portion of the error is referencing "'c:/users/abele'~1/", and that `'~1` is causing a syntax error.